# Getting the number of line using grep

Tags: linux

I am trying using grep command to obtain the line number of a specific string from a txt file using linux.

For example, I have a text file that contains

```
asdf
ghjk
zxcv
```

If I grep this file for `asdf`, we will receive the integer with number 1.

If I grep this file for `zxcv`, we will receive the integer with number 3.

How can return the line number with grep?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: This needs a lot more information. Are you returning 1 because it matches "asdf" exactly or is there some other logic that has to be applied? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried  `grep -c "ghjk" file.txt` and i was waiting to take 2 because `ghjk` is on line 2. But i took 1. The integer i want to be returned when i search for `ghjk` is 2  and when i search for `zxcv` is 3

Answer (score 2):

To return the line number from grep, use the `-n` switch. You can pipe the output of `grep` to the `cut` command to parse out the `:<search_string>` as well.

`grep -n <pattern> <file> | cut -f1 -d:`

If your file(`test.txt`) has the below contents ...

```
asdf
ghjk
zxcv
asdf
```

You would get the following output for a single occurance ...

```
$ grep -n ghjk test.txt | cut -f1 -d:
2
```

You would get multiple line numbers returned in the case where your search criteria is in multiple lines within the file.

```
$ grep -n asdf test.txt | cut -f1 -d: 
1
4
```

Comment: Thanks.Yout answer is very close to what i want to write.  If i search for  `asdf` i want it to show me `1`  NOT `1:asdf`, Thanks ;-)

Comment: I have updated my answer to parse out the `:<search_string>` and only return the line number

Comment: Cool . This was exactly the answer that i was looking for.

Comment: No worries - if this is the correct answer, you should accept and vote up so that others can benefit as well.